# Probability of two IID random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent and identically distributed.

- Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are continous, then $P(X<Y) = 1/2$
- Give an example of two IID RVs $X$ and $Y$ such that $P(X<Y)\neq 1/2$

I can't make sense of ncmathsadist's answer. Can somebody clarify?

Comment: For the second, try a discrete process.  Why not start with the standard Bernoulli process...$X=\{0,1\}$ with probability $\frac 12$?

Comment: For the first part, we have by symmetry $\Pr(X\lt Y)=\Pr(Y\lt X)$. The sum $\Pr(X\lt Y)+\Pr(Y\lt X)+\Pr(Y=X)$ is $1$. But for a continuous distribution, $\Pr(X=Y)$ is $0$.

Comment: @lulu: $X=\{0,1\}; Y = \{0,1\}$. $P(X < Y) = P(X = 0)P(Y = 1) = \frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: Exactly!  The problem, as you'll have noticed, is that the probability of a tie is non-zero.  It is generally true that $P(X<Y)=\frac 12 \times (1-P(tie))$.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand ncmathsadist's answer for part I though ...

Comment: $P(Y < X)=\iint_{s<t}f_y(s) \; f_x(t) \; ds \; dt = \iint_{s<t}f_x(s) \; f_y(t) \; ds \; dt=P(X < Y)$ because $f_x = f_y$ and then look at Andre's comments.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean "absolutely continuous" so both have a density. In that case, you have
$$P(X < Y) ~=~ \iint_{\{(s,t)\mid s < t\}} f_X(s)~f_Y(t)~\mathrm d\,s~\mathrm d\,t$$
Notice the integrand is symmetric  in is arguments (since $f_X(u)=f_Y(u)$).  This will do the job.

Comment: I don't see how the integrand is symmetric for any $X$ and $Y$. Can you clarify?

Comment: Both densities are the same; $f_X = f_y$.  Put them both to some common function $f$.

Comment: So you have $\int\int_{\{(s,t)|s<t\}}f(s)f(t)dsdt$?