# symmetry of two IID random variables

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, random-variables, indefinite-integrals

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and identically distributed. The claim is that $P(X<Y)=P(X>Y)=1/2$. How do I prove this?

**My attempt**

Since they are IID $f_X=f_Y$. So $P(X<Y)=\int\int_{s<t} f_X(s)f_Y(t)dsdt=\int\int_{s<t} f(s)f(t)dsdt$

If this is correct, I just don't know how the above integral evaluates to $1/2$

Comment: You have $P(X<Y) + P(X=Y) + P(Y>X) = 1$, right?

Comment: As in [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748942/probability-of-two-iid-random-variables?noredirect=1#comment3585518_1748942), which is a duplicate of this,  this is only true if $P(X=Y)=0$.

Comment: All you have done here is to take the posted solution to [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748942/probability-of-two-iid-random-variables?noredirect=1#comment3585518_1748942) and passed it off as your own work.  If you have a question about that solution, post it as a comment to the person who posted it.